# Preventing select menu from opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

Possibly a silly question, but how do I prevent a select element in a form from showing its drop down menu when it's clicked on?  I tried the following:

```
$('select').click (function (e) {
    console.log (e);
    return false;
});
```

and

```
$('select').click (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault ();
    console.log (e);
});
```

But neither worked.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: The reason I need to know is for a jquery enhanced select element that needs to degrade gracefully.  The idea is the select, when clicked, opens a jquery UI dialog with a nicely maked up list that the user makes their selection from (clicking a list item causes the select's value to update).  If JS is disabled then the select should just operate as normally.

The problem is that as well as the dialog opening, the dropdown also appears, which is not what I want.  I can't just disable the control, as its value needs to be submitted along with the rest of the form.

Comment: What about disabling the select itself?

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you are trying to do this. It doesn't really make sense to this and the most obvious answer would be: If you don't want a select element to open, then don't use a select element.

Comment: It's for a selection that's supposed to degrade gracefully.  Detailed explanation coming in a question edit.

Comment: Check this plugin: [jQuery Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

Comment: @GordonM: In that case I would use the script to replace the select with a button or a link and style it nicely :-)

Comment: @RoToRa: I suspect it's going to come down to hiding the select and putting something else in its place that sends events to it.  If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best solution would be to replace the select element with something else to click on (a button or a link).

BTW, you may want to look into the CSS 3 property [`appearance`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#appearance), which theoretically allows you to let that replacement element look like a dropdown. Support is however currently very limited:

- http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: I recommend check out the Allenph's answer somewhere below.

Answer (score 85):

This should work:-

```
$('#select').on('mousedown', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.blur();
   window.focus();
});
```

Comment: We have a winner. I saw another solution that omitted this.blur() and window.focus(). It didn't work every time; your solution does, thanks.

Comment: top work @deniz-ozger you wouldn't believe how much time i've burned trying to solve this

Comment: @DaveNottage just `preventDefault()` seems to work for me...can you share other ways it wouldn't work?

Comment: @Werlang I'm doing very little Javascript these days, however I suspect that it might not work across all browsers; perhaps it does now? My last job we had to support IE10/11, the latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: @DaveNottage I've just tried on Firefox and seems to work too. Couldn't test on IE though.

Comment: Works on IE11 too (and `mousedown` is very important in that case!), should be the excepted answer!

Comment: Beware that a select menu can also be opened with keyboard interaction. Eg, in Safari a user may tab to a <select> and hit the up/down keys to select an option. This would not trigger the `mousedown` event.

Comment: This code not working with label associated to select

Comment: The correct answer is the one below with `mousedown`

Answer (score 47):

The problem is that you're using the wrong event.

```
<select onmousedown="(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })(event, this)">
  <option>Some Option</option>
</select>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trnoht9k/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. You don't need to blur the dropdown, you just need to `preventDefault` but on `mousedown`, not `click` which happens after `mousedown`.

Comment: Doesn't work in FF for me (116.0b4)

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, if i need to disable something, the easiest way to have another invisible element on it (use absolute positioning). When you want to allow default behavior again, you just hide absolute element.

Answer (score 2):

You can, the trick is to cancel the mousedown event, not the click. The event chain is made in such a way that click and mouseup cannot occur if mousedown was cancelled:

```
function cancelDropDown(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById("selectElement").addEventListener("mousedown", cancelDropDown, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the select options on page load (if Javascript enabled). They will not display when the select box is clicked, but the text of the first option ("Select an option", or whatever) will still appear in the select field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfSelect option').css('display', 'none');
});
```

**Updated Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfSelect').focusin(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('body').click(function(event) {
            $(this).unbind(event);
            $('#idOfSelect').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach doesn't work.  It causes everything in the select to vanish, including the currently selected item.

Comment: Hmm...This solution worked in Chrome, but I found that (at least) Firefox hides the selected item, as you mentioned. I'll add an updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this exact problem, by manipulating the 'size' attribute of select. Not very elegant, but worked. Hope its of some help to you.

```
<!-- Example select dropdown -->
<select id="select" onclick="tackleDropdown()">
</select>

<!-- The JS function -->
<script>
    function tackleDropdown(){
        document.getElementById('select').setAttribute('size', 0);

        // your code for displaying the jQuery UI dialog (is it colorbox???)

        // re-enabling the drop down
        document.getElementById('select').setAttribute('size', document.getElementById('select').options.length);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers here. But still I had to make some additions.

```
$(document).on('keydown mousedown touchstart', 'select.disabled', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: This one works the best for me. The others do not disable the input field with keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **disabled**

```
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: It will still open the select list before disabling it. Best option would be to either disable the select before the click (some user action) or on `mouseenter` event.

Comment: @jSang:you are right.OP can do it on load or any particular event before clicking it.

Comment: Adding the disabled attribute will change the style of the select box to be grayed out, which does not sound like the intention of the poster.

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me, using Angular 2 (testing on Chrome). I put this in a (change) event and do $(event.srcElement).attr("disabled","disabled"); and it works great!! I then re-enable using setTimeout() when I want it to become enabled again.

Comment: Disabled sucks because you can't attached event handlers to it though

Answer (score -3):

A simple solution based on CSS is this small fragment:

```css
select:read-only * {
    display: none;
}
```

This will make the options not available when the select is selected. This action mimics the behavior of the "readonly" attribute of the input.